# How to see changes without building maven project?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin, build-management

I have simple java web application. web application has some js, css, html files. when I change js files, i am not able to view new changes in browser. For new changes i have to perform "mvn clean install" command then only i am able to see new changes. So Is there any way to see changes without performing this command ?

thanks.

Comment: Use a Tomcat etc. Plugin in Eclipse will do most of the things you like.

Answer (score 0):

it's not recommended to perform "mvn clean install" unless you want to use your code into another project.

That's what I do when I want to publish code change into a webserver for debug purposes

1/ I configure tomcat7-maven-plugin into the parent pom project:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

2/ then

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

will launch an embded tomcat7 server with your resources deployed.

**to publish** your code to a remote tomcat, you can use

```
tomcat7:deploy
```

after having configured tomcat7 plugin correctly

**alternatively**, import your maven project as an eclipse project (plugin name: m2e) then right click on the projet, debug on server will launch the eclipse configured tomcat.
whenever you save a resource, it will be automagically deployed on the eclipse-managed tomcat.